# groovy spread operator not work as closure parameter

Tags: groovy

```
def closureTwoParameter = {int i, j=1 -> println i + j}
def list = [1, 2]
closureTwoParameter *list
```

When i run above code ,the error is

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Main.multiply() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList) values: [[1, 2]]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Main.multiply() is applicable for argument types: (ArrayList) values: [[1, 2]]
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:3)
```

If i eidt add () around **list** , it works

```
def closureTwoParameter = {int i, j=1 -> println i + j}
def list = [1, 2]
closureTwoParameter (*list)
```

can anyone explain the difference? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `a * b`, the Groovy compiler thinks that you want to multiply `a` with `b` and calls `a.multiply( b )` under the hood.

In your case you simultaneously used the `spread-operator` AND omitted the brackets of the method/closure call, which resulted in Groovy's attempt to call the `multiply()` on the 1st argument, which is reflected by the exception you got.

That means, that you can NOT use the `*` and omit the brackets, hence the way of invoking:

```
closureTwoParameter( *list )
```

Note, that you put the brackets NOT around the `list`, but as method's brackets for `closureTwoParameter`.